# String.Format is not formatting phone number

Tags: c#, asp.net, string-formatting

```
String.Format("{0:###-###-####}", customer.ContactHome); //NOT working (9891205789)
```

**BUT**

```
String.Format("{0:###-###-####}", Convert.ToInt64(customer.ContactHome)); //Works fine (989-120-5789)
```

but I don't want to Cast phone no due to some reason. How can I format phone no without casting?

Comment: whats ContactHome original type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using numeric formating (`"{0:###-###-####}"`) on a string `customer.ContactHome` that's why it's not working.

Answer (score 7):

If customer.ContactHome is string, you can do:

```
Regex.Replace(customer.ContactHome, "(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)", "$1-$2-$3");
```

or

```
customer.ContactHome.Substring(0,3) + "-" +
customer.ContactHome.Substring(3,3) + "-" + 
customer.ContactHome.Substring(6,4);
```

Comment: Are you using System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace ?

Answer (score 0):

If `customer.ContactHome` is a `string`, it will not get formatted using a numeric format, as it is already a string and the format string expect a number.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to cast your value and also to use regex, you can always use [String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1wwdcbf.aspx) methods like [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) to get a formatted string value.